# myprofile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

When I am opening a Firefox profile "myprofile" through selenium webdriver, not able to set the value of flash plugin true.

When I am opening Firefox profile by `firefox.exe -p` option and start my browser, I am able to change value of flash plugin property true manually and changes reflect.    Is there any way when we launch gecko driver with selenium webdriver, value of flash plugin become true automatically every time?

```
myprofile.setPreference("plugin.state.flash", 2);
```

Is above line is correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it's correct code, because second argument is *2*